# How can I find all Issues added to a projectversion during a time interval in jira (db)?

Tags: sql, database, jira

I'm trying to figure out a way to find all issues that have been added to a projectversion (aka a sprint) during a period of time. What I want is to show all issues that have been added, even if they later have been removed from the projectversion.

To find all "old" issues added to the projectversion I use this:

```
select ji.pkey, cg.AUTHOR, cg.CREATED, ci.OLDVALUE as old, ci.NEWVALUE as ny
from changegroup cg, changeitem ci, jiraissue ji where 
ci.FIELD = 'Fix Version'    
and cg.id = ci.groupid
and ji.PROJECT = 10012
and cg.issueid = ji.id
    and DATE(cg.CREATED) >= '2011-12-06'
    and DATE(cg.CREATED) <= '2011-12-14'
and ci.NEWVALUE = 10099
and ci.OLDVALUE is null
```

Then we need to find the issues that are created and added to the projectversion:

```
SELECT ji.pkey
FROM jiraissue ji, nodeassociation na, projectversion pv
WHERE na.SINK_NODE_ID = pv.id
    AND DATE(ji.created) >= '2011-12-06' 
    AND DATE(ji.created) <= '2011-12-14' 
    and ji.id = na.SOURCE_NODE_ID 
    and pv.id = 10099
```

OK, so this works more or less. The problem arises when a new issue is created and added to the projectversion for later to be removed. Since the nodeassosiation is removed, there are no traces of it ever being a part of the projectversion.

Anyone have a way to figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, maybe helps. 
If the trace is removed than it must be somehow preserved to be searched for. A good way to achieve this is by CustomFields. You can add a custom field to each issue in which will be the project version tracked. You can add an event listener which autofills the custom field with assigned project version (when some jira event is fired).

If one issue has only one project version you can search for it trivially. 
Otherwise the customfield must remember all version ids (maybe in format: "id1,id2,..") and you can text search the custom field for id. 
This is not a straightforward solution but should work.

See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+a+Custom+Field

Consider using JQL for querying if you are writing a JIRA plugin. Event listeners:
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Writing+JIRA+event+listeners+with+the+atlassian-event+library